# Search in N to N relation in SQL database

Tags: mysql

This is my database model:

[image]

What I need:

I need to input several terms and search for documents (document.text) that has all of these terms.

Example data:

**documents:**

```
id:1  text:dog cat train

id:2  text:dog cat train car

id:3  text:dog cat

id:4  text:dog
```

**terms:**

```
id:1 term:dog

id:2 term:cat

id:3 term:train

id:4 term:car
```

Example:

I want to search for document that has all the terms: `dog cat train`. The result would be document 1 and document 2 but NOT document 3 because it does not have `train` and NOT document 4 because it does not have `cat` or `train`.

My first attempt would be query like this:

```
select document.text from document join document_has_term on       
 document.iddocument=document_has_term.document_iddocument join term on
 term.idterm=document_has_term.term_idterm where term="kindness" and
 term="horrible"
```

This query does not select any posts but it reflects what I basically want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing every document can have a term only once, if you run

```
SELECT document_iddocument
    FROM document_has_term
    JOIN term ON (term_idterm = idterm)
    WHERE term IN ('cat', 'dog', 'train');
```

you will have three rows where each of the three terms is matched, two rows
if two terms match, and so on.

So

```
SELECT document_iddocument
    FROM document_has_term
    JOIN term ON (term_idterm = idterm)
    WHERE term IN ('cat', 'dog', 'train')
GROUP BY document_iddocument
    HAVING COUNT(document_iddocument) = 3;
```

will only output the document IDs with three matches.

*This query does not even need to access `document` at this stage.*

You can use this as a sub-SELECT to get document's whose iddocument is in this list of ids:

```
SELECT document.text FROM document WHERE iddocument IN
( the above select );
```

## More complex query

If you want to run more complex searches, then maybe you ought to look into text search with MySQL and use FULLTEXT capabilities.

Otherwise, you need to build the query starting from an "outer" language where you specify things like

```
cat AND NOT dog
```

which is not SQL, and translate this into a SQL query.

An efficient approach would try and determine, from a complex query such as "cat but not dog", which component is the most *limiting*. In this example if you have 2000 records, where cat is present in one hundred records, and dog is present in all but fifty, you need to consider:
- queries searching for the *presence* of a term are very efficient.
- queries searching for the *absence* of a term are very expensive.

And you would first run a query for cat, then remove the items that *do* contain dog.

This approach is also quite complex.

Another possibility, not very recommended for large databases, would be to scan the whole document_has_term table and look for the status of all the documents:

```
SELECT document_iddocument,
    SUM(IF(term = 'cat', 1, 0)) AS has_0,
    SUM(IF(term = 'dog', 1, 0)) AS has_1
    FROM document_has_term
    LEFT JOIN term ON (term_idterm = idterm AND term.term IN 
        ('cat', 'dog'))
GROUP BY document_iddocument;
```

This query you build in some external language and is made up of three parts: a *template*

```
SELECT document_iddocument,
    <OTHER_FIELDS>
    FROM document_has_term
    LEFT JOIN term ON (term_idterm = idterm AND term.term IN 
        <TERM_LIST>
GROUP BY document_iddocument;
```

which is fixed; a list of fields (one for each term); a list of terms. The longer the query, the longer the lists, and the cost increases linearly.

Now you have to translate your "textual query" into a series of "it's there/it isn't":

```
cat and not dog
```

becomes

```
(has_0) and not (has_1)
```

Actually you can integrate this into an HAVING clause, and so build your query like this:

```
SELECT document.* FROM document
WHERE iddocument IN (

SELECT document_iddocument
    FROM document_has_term
    LEFT JOIN term ON (term_idterm = idterm AND term.term IN 
    ('cat', 'dog') -- list of all terms used
    )
GROUP BY document_iddocument

    HAVING
    (SUM(IF(term = 'cat', 1, 0))!=0) -- for the term "CAT"
    AND NOT                          -- from the "textual query"
    (SUM(IF(term = 'dog', 1, 0))!=0) -- for the term "DOG"
);
```

[Here you can experiment with a little fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74cb2/1).

As long as you use a SQLish syntax for your textual query, **if you are careful against SQL injections**, [Bob is your uncle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle). If you aren't careful about sanitizing your input (only allowing valid terms and the keywords 'and', 'or', 'not' and parentheses, and using prepared queries with ? placeholders for the terms), then [Bobby](https://xkcd.com/327/) may well be your [daddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who%27s_your_daddy%3F_%28phrase%29)...

Comment: That is very helpfull but what if i dont know how many terms i am searching for ? For example   -WHERE term IN ('cat', 'dog', 'train')-  is subselect querry like this -WHERE term IN (SELECT term FROM term WHERE term="cat" and not term="dog")-

Comment: This is... much more complicated. I've attempted a simple solution for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the column you want to select and take only those having both terms

```
select document.text 
from document 
join document_has_term on document.iddocument=document_has_term.document_iddocument 
join term on term.idterm=document_has_term.term_idterm 
where term in ('kindness', 'horrible')
group by document.text 
having count(distinct term) = 2
```

Comment: That is very helpfull but what if i dont know how many terms i am searching for ? For example -WHERE term IN ('cat', 'dog', 'train')- is subselect querry like this -WHERE term IN (SELECT term FROM term WHERE term="cat" and not term="dog")

Comment: You are building the query somehow and there you must populate the `where` clause. Just determine how many `term`s that are and put that number in the `having` clause.